# Sending Mail from .NET C# using activesync

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, activesync

I cannot find any example in C# code (nor other languages and platforms) with send mail implementation. I managed to find and dl [code example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-Implementing-400b9507) with provisioning and folder sync tasks, but cannot find send mail example.

This is all from MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202897(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202897%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

BR,
JDK

Comment: As you need to send email as background process correct?

Comment: What is your context? ActiveSync is used to synchronize between a server and mobile application. I guess you are looking for the EWS Managed API. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Actually I need to write code for client app, in my case ASP.NET web page (Azure websites), but for now working on console demo app, just to test. I do not need EWS Managed API, because exchange server is hidden behind proxy (corporate) and it's not accessible from azure. So from my point of view only way my client can send mail to users (mail will be send as part of authentication process) is using ActiveSync...

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. Sorry the example below is a bit rough as it is a cut down version of a much bigger class I use.

VB.NET:

```
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
    Public Class Exchange

             Public Sub SendEmail(fromEmailAddress As String, toEmailAddress As String, body As String, subject As String)

         Dim exService = New ExchangeService(serverVersion)
            exService.AutodiscoverUrl(fromEmailAddress)


            Dim msg As New EmailMessage(exService)
            msg.Subject = subject

            msg.Body = body

         msg.ToRecipients.Add(New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress(toEmailAddress,toEmailAddress))

            msg.SendAndSaveCopy()

    End Sub
End Class
```

C#

```
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

public class Exchange
{

    public void SendEmail(string fromEmailAddress, string toEmailAddress, string body, string subject)
    {

        dynamic exService = new ExchangeService(serverVersion);
        exService.AutodiscoverUrl(fromEmailAddress);


        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(exService);
        msg.Subject = subject;

        msg.Body = body;

        msg.ToRecipients.Add(new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress(toEmailAddress, toEmailAddress));

        msg.SendAndSaveCopy();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for replay, as I said in comments above, I cannot use exchange web service because corporate server is behind proxy and there are many security rules... not eve sure how exchange is expose towards internet... I tried few days ago EWS and for sure not manual not autodiscover service are not working from internet.. only from vpn, but my client is on azure website...